# how to apply the background only to the portion of a div that has content?

Tags: javascript, html, css

A `div` will take up the entire row. But let's suppose that the content, text, only goes up to 50% of the row. How to specify that the background should only go up to 50% of the row of the `div`, where the content lives?

IE where there is no content, the background should be transparent?

Comment: Please show your code here.

Comment: Please could you be a bit more specific about the requirement as it can be read that you want 50% to have a background but (I think!) you mean only the part that has content should have a background. Does this mean that in the case of wrapped text the background could have variable widths?

Comment: You can't. Css cannot detect your content so this is not possible. Alternatively, consider restructuring your HTML to include inline elements.

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap your content into an element with `display:inline-block;background: your-background-here`:

```css
.content>*{
  display:inline-block;
  background: lightpink;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
.content{
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
<span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing</span>
</div>
```